# How do I check-in for a flight using an e-ticket?

Tags: air-travel, tickets

I recently booked a flight from Ireland to America and the email I received contained the following banner:

[image]

How do I check-in for a flight using an e-ticket?

Can I check in with this email open on my phone?

Will all major airports accept an e-ticket?

Comment: Take a printout or give the reference number of your booking at the check-in desk. Or check-in online using the airline's website.

Comment: Basically all tickets on commercial airlines have been "E-tickets" for some years now; this airline appears to be conflating *ticket* with *boarding pass*, which is something different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I first read your question, I thought you might be referencing mobile-checkin, which is starting to become popular. As I looked into your question, I think this is just fancy wording for the ability to show your email at a checkin counter, where they will pull up your info and print your boarding pass.

Taken from [wikipedia electronic ticket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_ticket#Checking_in_with_an_e-ticket):

> To check in for a flight with an e-ticket, the passenger usually goes
>   to the check-in counter in the usual manner. There they may be
>   required to present some personal identification, a credit card or the
>   e-ticket itinerary receipt. Theoretically it is not even necessary to
>   present the e-ticket itinerary receipt document or quote the
>   confirmation code or e-ticket number as the reservation is confirmed
>   solely on the basis of the passenger's identity, which may be proven
>   by a passport or the matching credit card. However, producing a
>   print-out of the itinerary receipt is required to enter the terminal
>   of some airports as well as to satisfy immigration regulations in most
>   countries.
>
> At the check-in counter, the passenger checks-in his/her luggage and
>   receives a boarding pass. However, electronic ticketing allows various
>   enhancements to checking-in.

If your ticket does give you a barcode with a seat number (like below), then you can use this as your actual boarding pass. TSA and the gate attendants just ask to place your mobile device on their scanner. I typically use this for domestic flights in the states, but I haven't seen this for international flights from the US.

[image]

Comment: FYI I have seen qr code tickets (and used them) in international flights across Europe.

Comment: Same in Asia, electronic tickets on Cellphone screen are common for international flights.

Comment: FYI Emirates has this for their flights departing from Dubai (and only Dubai).